# rmarkdown::render output dir and output file DO NOT work

Tags: r-markdown

I am using render to produce a pdf:

```
rmarkdown::render("C://Users//myrmd.Rmd")
```

that works but when I add an output file and directory it does not work:

```
rmarkdown::render("C://Users//myrmd.Rmd",
output_file="C://...//myfolder//mypdf.pdf),
output_dir="C://.....//myfolder))
```

this returns an error Error: `pandoc document conversion failed with error 43`

Can you advise what the issue is here?

I have rmarkdown v1.8

Answer (score 7):

The `output_file` is only for the name of the file. Not the path.
You also have too many parenthesis.
Try with:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  "C:/Users/myrmd.Rmd",
  output_file = "mypdf.pdf",
  output_dir = "C:/...../myfolder"
)
```

Comment: I need quotes around output file and output dif but that still does not work